# Where can I get some Kovan Ethers?

Tags: kovan

I tried to get some Kovan ethers, but all the site/faucets I get revered to by MetaMask don't seem to work. Anyone any suggestions or maybe even some spart Kovan Ethers? My address is: 0xa8323F5fBcf1980B2093a633cF03020900B81d53 thanks!

Comment: Just checked my wallet I did receive some via the normal way, but could us a few extra for an upcoming masterclass smart contracts I'll be giving where I want to use the Kovan netwerk to deploy test smart contracts, so any tips still welcome!

Comment: Kovan is deprecated. If you need any free Goerli testETH, Alchemy runs this one - https://goerlifaucet.com. You can get more every day, although I find it enough for my testnet needs. 

For context, Goerli is the only Ethereum testnet running bc of the recent Ethereum Merge. All others including Ropsten, Rinkeby and Kovan have been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Googling gave me [This about Kovan Faucet](https://github.com/kovan-testnet/faucet)

There are currently a few different methods of receiving Kovan Ether:

- Icarus Faucet (SMS Verified, Automated)
- Request Via Gitter (Manually Verified)
- Use PoW via SmartPool

### Github Gist Faucet ( Automated )

Go to http://gist.github.com and then create a new entry with the text being your Kovan address, once you save this your browser should have reloaded at a new url. This url needs to be passed to the gist faucet at http://github-faucet.kovan.network/url

```
curl http://github-faucet.kovan.network/url --data "address=https://gist.github.com/[github_username]/[gist_hash]"
```

Comment: SmartPool doesn't work anymore. Github site states: Smartpool was live on Kovan testnet altough since Kovan is PoA rather than PoW mining had to be faked. Smartpool no longer runs on Kovan, Ropsten must be used instead.